# java, give int value in main, and the use that value in other class (can't just use classname.intname)

Tags: java, int

i want to take the value "slag", which i keep giving a random value and use it in the class "spiller". I can post the rest of my code if it is needed.

```
public static void main(String[] arg)
  {
    Matadorspil spil = new Matadorspil();
    spil.spillere.add(new Spiller("Phillip",50000));   // opret spiller Søren
    spil.spillere.add(new Spiller("Jaqob",50000));   // opret spiller Gitte
    spil.spillere.add(new Spiller("Rune",500000));

    // løb gennem 20 runder (40 ture)
    for (spil.spillersTur=0; spil.spillersTur<400000; spil.spillersTur++)
    {
      // tag skiftevis Søren og Gitte (% er forklaret i afsnit Fejl: Henvisningskilde ikke fundet)
      Spiller sp = spil.spillere.get(spil.spillersTur % spil.spillere.size());
      int slag = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;     // og slå et terningkast (1-6)
      System.out.println("***** "+sp.navn+" på felt "+sp.feltnr+" slår "+slag);
      for (int i=1; i<=slag; i=i+1)                  // nu rykkes der
      {
        // gå til næste felt. Hvis vi når over antal felter så tæl fra 0
        sp.feltnr = sp.feltnr + 1;
        if (sp.feltnr == spil.felter.size()) sp.feltnr=0;
        Felt felt = spil.felter.get(sp.feltnr);

        if (i<slag) felt.passeret(sp); // kald passeret() på passerede felter
        else felt.landet(sp);          // kald landet() på sidste felt
        try { Thread.sleep(300); } catch (Exception e) {} // vent 0.3 sek
      }
      try { Thread.sleep(30); } catch (Exception e) {} // tur slut, vent 3 sek
    }
  }
```

class i want to use it in:

```
   public class Bryggeri extends Felt{
    Spiller ejer;
    double pris;
    double grundleje;
    public Bryggeri(String navn, double pris, double leje){
        this.navn = navn;
        this.pris = pris;
        this.grundleje = leje;
    }

    public void landet(Spiller sp){
        sp.besked("Du er landet på "+navn);
        if (sp==ejer){
            sp.besked("Det er din egen grund");
        }
        else if (ejer==null){
            if (sp.konto > pris){
                if (sp.spørgsmål("købe "+navn+" for "+pris)){
                    sp.transaktion( -pris );
                    ejer=sp;
                }
            }
            else sp.besked("Du har ikke penge nok til at købe "+navn);
        }
        else{
            sp.besked("Leje: "+grundleje);
            sp.betal(ejer, grundleje);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: make it public and static if you want to use it like classname.intname.

Comment: Please post a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Oh, and definitely DON'T make it public and static. That way lies madness.

Comment: Do you want to use the value slag in another class?

Comment: Yes, i'll add the class i want to use it in

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the value in another class,try to create a setter and getter for this value `slag`:

```
 private int slag;

public int getSlag() {
    return slag;
}

public void setSlag(int slag) {
    this.slag = slag;
}
```

You can do this in your first class where you have the value `slag` try to add the code above, and in you second classwhere you want to use it in your main method set it like:

```
 class1 cl1 = new class1();
    cla1.setSlag(999);
```

and this value in you code, use `getSlag()` to retrieve the value.
For more info go in [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html)